# How to make a premium discord.py command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to allow some people that i have added to  a list to be able to use certain commands this is what i got so far please help me

````
@client.command()
async def premium(ctx):
  premium = set()
  premium.add(user_id)
  if user_id in premium:
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Just a Test Command", description="Trying to make a premium command", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://images4.alphacoders.com/980/thumb-350-980708.png")
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by Cortax#1667")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
  
  else:
    await ctx.channel.send("You are not a premium user")```
````

Comment: I don't see any mistakes, it looks right

Comment: it says user_id isnt defined

Comment: save the list to a json file load it and use it. [json with python tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: You might also want to add a check instead of checking for it inside the function as it might get messy for more commands.

Comment: Read the docs of how to get user id from message you receive. In discord.js it is message.author.id, it should be similar in discord.py

Comment: this is discord.py

Answer (score 1):

It don't work because u forget about user_id
Let's use:

```
user_id = ctx.user.id
```

Or exchange to:

```
premium.add(ctx.user.id)
```

Comment: Will not work, premium is a local variable and will not be usable in other commands.

Comment: what could i do to fix this?

Comment: You have to create a json file and store user data there, or a database.

Comment: What is the function set?